# Get Publication "Title" from IdentifiableObject in tridion2011 events

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I have an Tridion.ContentManager.IdentifiableObject which may be a Page/Component etc and I wish to get the title of the publication it belongs to.

I am current able to get the publicationId like so:

```
IdentifiableObject.Id.PublicationId
```

but I wish to get the Publication title without doing a round trip to tridion. Is this possible?

Comment: Nice question, could we interest you in committing to the [Area 51 Tridion specific proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38335/tridion?referrer=gPujQMxthNCNn9xqeeO2NA2). Sign up with the same SO account if you have a moment.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is possible. First of all cast your object to `RepositoryLocalObject` instead of `IdentifiableObject` and then you can do:

```
var item = (RepositoryLocalObject) subject;
item.OwningRepository.Title;
```

Comment: Depending on what you need, you could also get to the title of the ContextRepository (which is different from the OwningRepository if the item is shared).